# DB Design for parking lot reservation

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am building uni project which is for managing parking lots in which places can be booked. I'm using Postgres.

Parking lots are usually open weekdays from certain hours. It might happen that during the normal schedule, a bank holiday is there so it should not operate at that time.
Parking lot have capacity which is stored, but not individual places.

Users can place a reservation for a place in a lot if:

1. Lot is open at that time
2. There's a free place

Now I'm struggling to figure out how to model time of operation for a parking lot.

Say we have parking lot

```
ParkingLot
id,
name,
address

Reservation
id
parkingLotId,
licensePlate,
from_timestamp,
to_timestamp
```

**How do I store operating hours ?**

Comment: @Jasen how to store hours and days when parking lot is available for reservation ? Some of them might be open everyday, and some of them weekdays only. There also bank holidays etc.

Comment: 1. You'll need at least three entities, `ParkingLot`, `ParkingLotAvailability`, and `Reservation`.  2. Ditch the `Ids` - they are not keys, only pointers.  If you're going to build a relational database and take advantage of the power and speed that comes with that, you'll need keys.

Comment: Similar to, and possibly duplicate of, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163642/parking-spots-availability-design

Comment: Also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27292/how-would-i-build-a-data-model-for-parking-lot-hours-and-respective-parking-fees … both of these are in the Related sidebar. Seems a common problem….